# What is ++== in Java?

Tags: java, operators

1. Searched this site, found no reference.
2. Test code:

   ```
   int[] test = {0, 1, 2, 3};
   System.out.println("test1[3] ++== 0 is " + (test[3] ++== 0));
   ```
3. Result:

test1[3] ++== 0 is false

So it must be some sort of logical operator but I have not been able to find any documentation.  Searching the Internet yielded no reference.

Please help?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(test[3]++) == 0`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way the text is presented looks like it would be a special case `++==`, but in fact you should read it as follows:

`test[3]++ == 0`

Basically, the result of `test[3]++` will be compared (i.e `==`) with `0`.

And this basically reads as `(test[3]=3) == 0`, which is false.

The `++` is a postfix operator which is shortcut for `value = value + 1`.

The `==` is a comparison between two values.

The text is just badly formatted, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

`++` and `==` are two independent operators. `++` is post-incrementing the value of `test[3]`, then that is being compared to 0.

Answer (score 1):

`x++==y` is equivalent to `x++ == y`

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[] test = {0, 1, 2, 3};
        System.out.println("test1[3] ++== 0 is " + (test[3] ++== 3));
    }
}
```

`test1[3] ++== 0` will equate to `false`.

`test1[3] ++== 3` will equate to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

It's two operators - increment by one (`x++`) and test for equality `(x==0)`. You should read it as `(x++) == 0`.

The tricky thing is that the increment happens after the comparison, so the above means "test if X is zero, then increment X by one."

Answer (score 1):

Since ++ is a post-increment, your actions can be separated as:

- Compare an element with index 3 and 0 -> test[3] != 0 -> `false`
- Increment element with index 3. -> `test[3] = test[3] + 1;`

So after that in the `test[3]` will be value 4